# Want Procedural Approach In Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want main activity to wait while dialog box is excuted. I tried `this.wait();` in main activity but it gives exception. This is all crossed my mind so I am here to ask for help :). Thank you in advance
Any Help Will Be Appreciated

```
public class MyDailogTestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    String Xvalue,Yvalue;
    TextView TextViewString;    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button ShowDialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ShowDialog);
        TextViewString = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ShowDialogText);      
        ShowDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Dialog MyDialog = MyDailog();
                MyDialog.show();
                // I WANT THIS TO EXECUTE AFTER BELOW MENTIONED CODE
                TextViewString.setText(Xvalue + Yvalue);
            }

        });
    }

    private Dialog MyDailog(){
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, null);
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(MyDailogTestActivity.this)
        .setTitle("Enter Value")
        .setView(textEntryView)
        .setPositiveButton("Oky", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // THIS TO BE EXECUTE FIRST       
                Xvalue = "This ";
                Yvalue = "and That";                
                /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                /* User clicked cancel so do some stuff */
            }
        })
        .create();        
    }

}
```

This is images of this project while executing

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/220/11696639.jpg/
In this image you can see Hello World unchanged. I am trying to reflect the change in hello world TextView.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/338/27833231.jpg/
Now in this image. When I hit show dialog it carry on executing the next code `TextViewString.setText(Xvalue + Yvalue);`
in which it shows the value null
now I want it to wait for dialog box to finish code in which Xvalue and Yvalue will have the value "This n That" by this code

```
Xvalue = "This ";
Yvalue = "and That";
```

Comment: `show()` is not a blocking call.

Comment: means ? please elaborate :) Thank you for considering the problem :)

Comment: The `show()` method on a `Dialog` is not a blocking call. Execution continues immediately with the statement following the call to `show()`. In fact, `show()` does not show the dialog -- rather, a request is put on a work queue, managed by the main application thread, which will show the dialog eventually. Notably, the dialog will not appear until after your `onClick()` method where you are calling `show()` returns. This sort of asynchronous work is called "event-driven programming", and it has been used by most quality UIs for the past quarter-century or so. Please do what Tim told you to do.

Comment: is there any way i can make program to give control to dialog box until it dialog box finishes and then it will return control back to onclick method again ?

Comment: No. Please do what Tim told you to do.

Comment: thank you for your elaborated explanation. i will be using tim solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move this line:

```
TextViewString.setText(Xvalue + Yvalue);
```

to your positive button click listener like this:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    // THIS TO BE EXECUTE FIRST    
    Xvalue = "This ";
    Yvalue = "and That";                
    /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
    TextViewString.setText(Xvalue + Yvalue);
}
```

Comment: nice but it's not the solution i am looking for. i want main activity to wait until the dialog finished :).. thanks for the reply :)

Comment: What do you mean wait? it will be waiting. The onClickListener is your last statement inside onCreate() after it completes the activity won't be running any code until either (A) the dialog button listener get a callback, or (B) another lifecycle method such as onPause() gets called by the system.

Comment: right but activity doesn't wait for dialog to finish. it creates a new thread in which dialog will be executed and in the mean while it carry on executing the code in onCreat. try to run code.. you will see should i add images of execution ? i wanted to but stackoverflow did'nt let me

Comment: Is there more code to your activity than you posted? There is absolutely nothing in the code that you posted that would start a new thread...

Comment: NO this is the code... i have'nt posted the code of Main.xml and MyDialog.XML.. should i ??

Comment: If this is all of your code then what exactly is it doing after your dialog is shown and before the okay button is pressed? From what you've posted it seems like there is nothing happening during this time. Definitely not a thread being created. Where are you seeing something that indicates a new thread has been made?

Comment: i added the link of project in execution. please give it a look

Comment: it is putting the nullnull in your TextView because you are calling setText right after you create the dialog instead of waiting until one of the buttons is pressed... If you move the setText statement to the positive button onClick like I showed in my answer it will not change the text in the TextView until after you press the ok button on the dialog... that is how you want it to behave isn't it?

Comment: yes this is how i want it to behave but i am designing a Scientific calculator App in which every time a button is pressed for calculation ..lets say X raised To Y is pressed.. it takes the value from dialog box and then i use these value in a function and calculate the result and then print.. now if i would use this approach then i will be needing to make many dialog box or i have to  add big code in dialog box. i am looking it as learning prospective in which while solving this problem ( means to Force main activity to wait while dialog execution is finished ) i will learn more about android

Comment: thank you for giving it a look... nd considering problem..  will try the way you showed

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if u can do what u r trying to do but I can suggest an alternative which  think is a standard. Create a listener of the type `DialogInterface.OnDismissListener` and then set it to your dialog using `setOnDismissListener()`. This listener will be called when you dismiss the dialog.

or else if you don't have any heavy logic, you can directly put it in the dialog like Tim suggested.

Comment: as i said in above comment  i want main activity to wait until the dialog is finished :). i created this test project but i have a another main project which i am developing in which i need such execution. surely i will make another way to implement my logic if this can not be done but i am sure there would be someway to do it